# How to create a file and its parent directories in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, directory, filepath

I want to write content to a file by a non-trivial path and create all parent directories if they don't exist. So the following code:

```
mkFile "foo/bar/baz/quux.txt"
```

will create all directories `foo/`, `foo/bar/` and `foo/bar/baz/` if they don't exist (and the file `quux.txt` as well of course). What is the easiest way to implement such a function? Ideally, I would like to see a solution that uses only `directory` and `filepath` libraries.

Comment: Have you seen `createDirectoryIfMissing`?  It does all the directory creation you ask for then you just need to write `""` to your file (catching any exceptions as you see fit).

Comment: Yes, I have seen. This function doesn't do what is required. `createDirectoryIfMissing True "foo/bar.txt"` creates two directories and not one directory and one file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm trying to find the easiest way for this but can't find any.
The only way is to implement our own function based on your needs.
Fortunately, this is using `System.Directory` and `System.FilePath.Posix` libraries only.

```
import Prelude

import System.Directory (createDirectoryIfMissing)
import System.FilePath.Posix (takeDirectory)

main :: IO ()
main = createAndWriteFile "foo/bar/baz/quux.txt" "something"

createAndWriteFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO ()
createAndWriteFile path content = do
  createDirectoryIfMissing True $ takeDirectory path

  writeFile path content
```

Below is the result based on the code above.

```
foo
└── bar
    └── baz
        └── quux.txt
```

You may edit the code however you like.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It's also excellent that it works on files like `foo.txt` because `takeDirectory` returns `.` and `createDirectoryIfMissing` does nothing in such cases. I haven't tested it on Windows, but since I'm on Linux, this works for me.